# Identify an array of objects by object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, oop

My question:

I have an array of objects as such

```
var people = [
        {name: 'Dan'  ,  age: '20', favoriteColor : 'blue'}, 
        {name: 'Bob'  ,  age: '35', favoriteColor : 'red' }, 
        {name: 'Frank',  age: '22', favoriteColor : 'green'}, 
        {name: 'Ed'   ,  age: '27', favoriteColor : 'yellow'}
]
```

I need to be able to identify the objects in the array by their name property. [It's important to note that the name property for each object in the array WILL be unique]. However, they are not ordered by any particular pattern. So people[0] may or may not equal the object with a 'name' of 'Dan'.

I want to be able to access the data by organizing it so that

```
people.Dan
```

returns the object

```
{age: '20', favoriteColor: 'blue'}
```

I feel like this should be relatively simple, but I don't really know the words to describe the issue to be able to find the proper solution.

EDIT: For anyone reading this in the future, I decided to go with Elliot's solution instead of using underscore.js. They both solve the problem, but it ended up being easier just to implement another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#find). They have a method called findWhere which does exactly what you need. The method _.where will return an array if there is more than one matching object.

```
_.findWhere(people, {name: "dan"});
// will return
// {name: 'Dan', age: '20', favoriteColor: 'blue'}
```

Comment: It's generally bad form to recommend including an entire library for the use of one function. Furthermore the OP is working with Node.js, and it can be a pain to get Underscore to work with Node.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I disagree, first, lodash is super easy to work with in node, and second, these are small utility libraries that are extremely useful. If OP doesn't have a utility-belt library which can do what he is asking, he should.

Comment: I've have never used underscore.js, but I've heard a lot of positive feedback from people that have used it/written about it on the web. Not sure if I should go this route, just for the sake of checking it out, even though the solution provided by Elliot Bonneville looks solid as well...

Comment: Well, @Dan, I would definitely not discourage you from checking out Underscore and/or lodash. They're both useful libraries and you'd get a lot of mileage out of either of them. However, you might directly learn more if you went and copied out `findWhere` from one of them to see how it works (you'll likely find it's similar to the solution I provided).

Comment: Elliot's solution is great, but you need to abstract it so that the code can be used in many situations, whenever you need to do this kind of thing, you can either do this yourself, or just use a library.

Comment: @watson: The code I provided can be easily abstracted, and doing so would be a great learning experience. My personal advice when it comes to libraries is something along the lines of "don't use it if you can't do it yourself." A utility library should be just that: a utility, not a replacement for your own knowledge.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville You make a very good point, but sometimes it is necessary to use things you don't fully understand, though it is best to keep trying to decipher them. I wouldn't know anything about programming if I didn't use code I didn't understand.

Answer (score 3):

Right now `people` is an array. You need to restructure it into an object, where each name is a property returning the rest of that object. Here's one way to do that:

```
var tempPeople = {};
for(var i = 0, len = people.length; i<len; i++) {
    tempPeople[people[i].name] = people[i];
}

people = tempPeople;
```

You could also leave `people` as an array and instead use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select by name:

```
var dan = people.filter(function(person) { return person.name == "Dan" })[0]; // returns the first person named Dan
```

Answer (score -1):

Make an object constructor. Write a custom method.

```
function person(name,age,favoriteColor) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.favoriteColor = favoriteColor;
    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.age + " - " + this.favoriteColor;
    }
}

var people = [];

people.push(new person('dan','20','blue'));

alert(people[0].getInfo());
```

Comment: This doesn't allow the OP to select users by name, however, which is what he was looking to do. -1

Comment: Yes it freakin does. just alert(people[0].name);

Comment: Whoops, sorry, just got it.